# Image not parsing from xml

Tags: android, xml-parsing, android-listview

I have a xml that i'm parsing using a DOM parser.  Its supposed to pull an image and load it into my list view along with the Title and pub date.  It is only loading the default image if no image if found in the xml file yet i know there is an image in the xml file.  Instead of filling this with a long list of all my activities i'm providing a link to my dropbox so the code can be checked out.  Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.  THank you

here is the link
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/29qkueuxatlcwn8/0DDI7tPQfe